# RequestGuard::attempt does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying multiguard authentication for api when i login for admin i am getting
following error

> BadMethodCallException
>   Method Illuminate\Auth\Req
>   uestGuard::attempt does not exist.

here is my login method in controller

```
 public function login(Request $request){
    if(Auth::guard('admin-api')->attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')]))
    {

  // if successful, then redirect to their intended location


        $user = Auth::guard('admin-api');
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('admin')->accessToken;
        return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus);
    }
    else{
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401);
    }
}
```

my api.php

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {


Route::post('login', 'API\Admin\AdminController@login')->name('admin.login');
Route::post('register', 'API\Admin\AdminController@register')->name('admin.register');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:admin-api'], function(){
 Route::post('get-details', 'API\Admin\AdminController@getDetails');
});


});
```

my admin model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
 use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
 protected $table = 'admin';
 protected $guard = 'admin-api';
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
```

}

please tell me any other inputs you want

Answer (score 3):

A better hack is this

```
   $credentials = ['email' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password];

   //Since we are not using guard web in API request, we have to add it here ( 
   // guard('web') ) to access the Auth::attempt function,
   // the Auth::attempt needs web guard and crsf token, but using it here bypasses 
   // the post with crsf.
    if (Auth::guard('web')->attempt($credentials, false, false)) {
    dd('user is OK');
    }else{
   dd('user is NOT OK');
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I followed many tutorials, got this error and never knew why. You explained it perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Laravel Facade for Auth does not expect you to use it for the api guard since sessions and cookies will be set, Thus does not support `->attempt()` function. But the API middle-ware disables session and cookies since it is stateless. So here is the hack.
Get to your confi\auth and create a similar web instance for your api guards thus

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'drivers-web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'drivers',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',//previously "token"
        'provider' => 'users',//This will be switched regularly from the middleware between drivers and users
    ],

    'drivers-api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',//previously "token"
        'provider' => 'drivers',
    ],
],
```

Never the less, You can use passport to generate your client access tokens which are stateless sessions. And also serve well for  authentication.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use **Auth::guard('admin-api')->attempt** with a guard with driver value is **token** or **passport** so you can repeat the guard and make one with **session** driver and the second one with **passport** then you can use the session one to make difference between earch other you can see a [reference and source code from here 
https://web-brackets.com/discussion/103/method-illuminate-auth-requestguard-attempt-does-not-exist-](https://web-brackets.com/discussion/103/method-illuminate-auth-requestguard-attempt-does-not-exist-)

Answer (score -2):

To me, I changed drivers for the web from passport to session. Laravel's cache had to be cleared to be able to go back to the session driver

```
php artisan cache:clear
```